# Website with auto updating image from latest file in folder

Tags: image, web, google-drive-api

I am a noob with everything related to coding, except for some knowledge of the linux command line. Anyway, I have this idea for a project. I need a website with an image that updates every few hours or so. I have a folder in google drive, and every few hours a new image is uploaded. These times are not regular, but as long as the website gets the new photo within an hour-2hours, it will be fine. I was thinking of making an alias folder that links to the latest image in a folder (like how apple does it with time machine backups) if that makes sense. Then I would copy the link on google drive (of the alias folder) and put that into wordpress. It would pull that link, which would go to the latest image in a folder. I have a feeling that this would not work out, however. Basically, I just want an automated updater to pull the latest image from a google drive folder and publish it to the website. If it needs to be local, I could use the backup and sync for drive and the google drive folder would be synced to my local machine.

Another thing I was thinking of was a automatic slideshow maker. I would use some kind of script in google to delete all files in a folder except for the latest one. Then I would use the automatic slideshow maker to make a slideshow based on data in the particular google drive folder, which would be the latest photo.

Again, these are just some ideas that I have had, and they are both likely not going to work.

I have a self hosted web server (docker) and could put a wordpress instance on that, or I could use an online website builder like weebly or wix or even google sites. It needs to be free because this is for a community service project and I do not want to have to constantly fundraise. However, if my only option requires payment, I am open to that.

Does anybody have a solution for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve what you desire.

## One approach:

I would suggest naming the image that you put in drive with the same filename. (renaming the old ones, as each new image is uploaded)

[Google Apps script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone) makes it easy (and free) to [deploy a Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web), and using it gives you the benefit of using it's [Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive) among others.

Use a [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) to execute a function that renames your images so that the most recently uploaded one has the name of the image your website is requesting.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I have found an awesome solution! First, I setup a google account and made a folder in google drive. Then, I downloaded an app called DriveSync. I used the app Automate (by llamalab) to take photos (you can program it however you want it to trigger the photo). The trigger happens, then it deletes a file called latest.jpg in the Automate Image folder (on the android phone). Then it takes a photo with an image name of latest.jpg. And all of this is synced to the remote Google Drive Folder thanks to DriveSync. So now we have a synced google drive folder. Then, I setup a Wordpress Instance. Get the Add-On called Image and video gallery from Google Drive here https://wordpress.org/plugins/skaut-google-drive-gallery/. Now, follow the steps to link up your google drive folder to it, and configure your website to display this addon on your page of choice. It will pull the only image in the folder we configured earlier, and it will display it on the website! Plus it auto updates. Also, you can configure the image size which is helpful as this was probably meant to display more than one photo, but with only one photo there is a lot of empty space.

Hope you found this helpful!